# Unicode Encode Error: Charmap cannot encode character \xa9 in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, decode, html-encode

Hi there I am writing scraping code but when i try to get all paragraph from website it give me following error
Unicode Encode Error: Charmap cannot encode character '\xa9'

here is my code:

```js
#Loading Libraries
import urllib
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#define URL for scraping
newsurl = "http://www.techspot.com/news/67832-netflix-exceeds-growth-expectations-home-abroad-stock-soars.html"
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(newsurl)

soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage ,"html.parser")

article = soup.find_all('div' , {'class','articleBody'})

for pg in article:
 paragraph = soup.findAll('p')
 ptag = paragraph
 print(ptag)
```

Error I am getting is following:

[image]

Let me how to remove this error

Comment: Don't try to print to console, which cannot display unicode. Instead for example write to a file with utf-8 encoding. Also `ptag` is not a string and hence no encode method. You could try `str(ptag).encode('ascii','ignore')`.

Comment: BTW. printing unicode to console is most probably already answered on SO. Possibly a duplicate.

Comment: fidn how to set utf-8 (cp65001) in console.

Comment: @mkiever thanks your given solution :*

Comment: [Change default code page of Windows console to UTF-8](http://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8)

Comment: @mkiever Python 3.6 on Windows bypasses the character mode I/O so that it can write Unicode directly. Upgrading is the easiest solution.

Comment: @furas not necessary anymore with Python 3.6.

Comment: @MarkRansom but still needed with 3.5 and 2.7

Answer (score 0):

soup.findAll() returns a ResultSet object which is basically a list which does not have an attribute encode. You either meant to use .text instead:

```
text = soup.text
```

Or, "join" the texts:

```
text = "".join(soup.findAll(whatever, you, want))
```

Answer (score 0):

At times this error occurs while using Beautiful soup 4 or bs4 or using getData requests or command . So try using the below mentioned code with your print statement.
print(myHtmlData.encode("utf-8"))